# python managing tasks in threads when using priority queue

Tags: python, queue

I'm trying to write a program which starts new tasks in new threads.
Data is passed from task threads to a single worker/processing thread via a priority queue (so more important jobs are processes first). 
The worker/processing thread gets higher priority data from the queue and limits calls to a REST API

How can I passed the data back to it's origionating task thread, while tracking that all that particular task threads data has been processed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your request queue entry include a response queue.  When finished place a response on the response queue.

The requesting thread waits on the response queue.

A callback method could alternately be used.